Expose ports dynamically to the internet inside Kubernetes
I'm working on deploying a VoIP app to Kubernetes. The app listens on the well-known port 5060/udp for SIP messages and then selects a dynamic port between 16000 and 17000 to receive RTP packets.
I know that exposing the well-known port 5060 to the outside world can be done using Kubernetes Services and an External Load Balancer. However, I'm having trouble finding a way to expose the dynamically chosen ports (between 16000 and 17000) publicly.
Additional Context:
To avoid port conflicts, I intend to deploy at-most one pod per node. However, I anticipate potential conflicts if I run multiple pods of the VoIP app on same node, as they might try to use the same dynamically chosen port.
How can I properly expose these dynamic RTP ports in a Kubernetes environment? What are the best practices for handling this scenario?
